# unrar all rar files in a directory with linux

Tags: linux, debian, rar

I am trying to extract many rar files at once, but with no successful. I am trying in the order:

```
>ls *.rar|xargs unrar x
>ls *.rar|xargs unrar e
>unrar e -r *.rar
>for f in *.rar;do unrar e “$f”;done
```

no ones works. Rar answers every times saying that there are not file to exctract.

```
>Extracting from damned_file.rar

 No files to extract
```

If I try to extract the file one by one, then all works fine

```
>unrar e damned_file.rar
 extracting damned_file.rar                        
 extracting dmaned_file.txt                            OK
 All OK
>
```

My version of rar is

```
UNRAR 4.10 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2012 Alexander Roshal
```

What I am doing wrong?

PS: The command

```
find . -name "*.rar" -exec unrar e {} \;
```

works fine, but the question remain the same. Why the previous commands fails?

Answer (score 15):

Here is my go-to for loop:

```
for file in *.rar; do unrar e "$file"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` puts arguments behind the command provided to it up until the maximum command length for your current shell, so the command would be:

```
xargs unrar e damned_file.rar another_damned_file.rar yadf.rar
```

However, `unrar` only takes a single rar file as argument. The find command you specified runs `unrar` for every single file it finds, so the command is `unrar e damned_file.rar`, `unrar e another_damned_file.rar`.

Comment: so why for loop won't work?

Comment: @mtak, isn't the option -n 1 solving that problem? `ls *.rar | xargs -n 1 -t unrar l ` shows that the arguments are distributed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is using the `xargs` option `-n 1`

```bsh
ls *.rar | xargs -n 1 unrar x
```

`-n 1` uses at most `1` argument per command line (see [xargs man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html))

Notice, though, that parsing the output of `ls` can easily lead to errors. A `for` cycle is always a much safer option.

You can read about this in [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 8, need use **unar** ,not **unrar**

```
find . -name "*.rar" -exec unar e {} \;
```